# Simplified regex for 2 digit numbers

Tags: regex

I have a regex to match the numbers starting `01-15` which works fine
`^^0[1-9]|[1-1][0-5]$$` but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this

Comment: Stick with this `Regex:   ^(?:0[1-9]|1[0-5])$
Options:  < m >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   15
Elapsed Time:    0.98 s,   983.11 ms,   983113 µs
Matches per sec:   762,882`

Comment: Or, this one slightly faster `Regex:   ^(?:0\d(?<!0)|1[0-5])$
Options:  < m >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   15
Elapsed Time:    0.96 s,   964.21 ms,   964206 µs
Matches per sec:   777,842`

Comment: The fastest possible of course is to get rid of the group syntax altogether, try this `Regex:   ^0[1-9]$|^1[0-5]$
Options:  < m >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   15
Elapsed Time:    0.91 s,   912.12 ms,   912121 µs
Matches per sec:   822,259`

Answer (score 3):

Your current pattern will sometimes match numbers in the middle of the string (rather than matching *only* full strings composed only of the desired number format). When you want to alternate, but also use `^` and `$` anchors, alternate inside a group instead.

Also, `[1-1]` is superfluous - you may just use `1`, no need for a character set. In addition, putting identical `^` or `$` anchors next to each other is the same as having just one of those anchors, so don't double up on them.

```
^(?:0[1-9]|1[0-5])$
```

https://regex101.com/r/wtj84A/2

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if it's only from 01-15 this is working fine: `^0[1-9]|[1-1][0-5])$` it's matching all numbers between them. This looks correct or can be simplified?

Comment: You should alternate only *inside* a group, because it looks like you want to match only at the start to the end of a string or line. A character set that matches only a single character is redundant, too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it that's different.
Care about performance ? It's the fastest way
because it has no grouping, which is an extra step.

`^0[1-9]$|^1[0-5]$`

Benchmark

```
 Regex2:   ^0[1-9]$|^1[0-5]$
 Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
 Matches found per iteration:   15
 Elapsed Time:    0.91 s,   912.12 ms,   912121 µs
 Matches per sec:   822,259
```

Answer (score 1):

I mean you can do it`^(0[1-9]|1[0-5])$` if you don't want to capture: `^(?:0[1-9]|1[0-5])$`

The `()` are necessary to ensure that the `0[1-9]` path doesn't claim the `^`.

You can try it out at https://www.debuggex.com/

But please be aware that the syntax and implementation can vary from language to language.